# How often does RESTful client pull server data

Tags: rest, pull

I have a RESTful web-service application that I developed using the Netbeans IDE. The application uses MySQL server as its back end server. What I am wondering now is how often a client application that uses my RESTful application would refresh to reflect the data change  in the server.

Are there any default pull intervals that clients get from the RESTful application? Does the framework(JAX-RS) do something about it  Or is that my business to take care of.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This totally depends on the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Abraham

There are no such rules. Only thing you can use for properly implementing this is HTTP's caching capabilities. Service must include control information how long representation of a particular resource can be cached, revalidated, never cached etc...

On client application side of things each client may decide it's own path how it will keep itself in sync with a service. It can be done by locally storing data and serve end user from local cache etc... Service can not(and shouldn't know) how clients are implemented, only thing service can do is to include caching information in response messages as i already mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

It is your responsibility to schedule the service to execute again and again. We can set time out interval but there is no pull interval.